# Loading data incrementally in bucketed table in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sample, bucket

I am still learning hive. I have referred few books for understanding concept of Buckets in hive. What i learnt is , if we enforce bucketing , it will create exactly same number of files as number of buckets.

In my Case, i will load the data  incrementally in bucketed table five times a day.
For ex: if i have table with 16 buckets, then each load it will create 16 files based on hash/samples. So totally for 5 runs , 80 files  will created.

```
My Question is , if i have table with 16 buckets defined on it with 80 files 
in HDFS, will it going to give bucketing benefits ?
```

Answer (score 1):

do you create a different table for each incremental loading?

which Hadoop distribution are you using?

I'm using that same strategy and every incremental loading generates (and override) the same number of buckets that i defined.

When we have permissions problems have duplicated files, because hive tables were created with hive user and populating was made with another (hdfs).

Look at in your /user/hive/warehouse directory for the owner/permissions of table directory , afterward look at in the subdirectories for the same (owner/permissions)

Comment: No , i am using same table for each loading. My plan to keep appending data. I am trying to see if it is going to give me bucket benefits when i have multiple file for each bucket.

Comment: We use for this case Insert Overwrite with result of union incremental data and old incremental data. In fact, part of old incremental data, that part wich is not present in new incremental data (filtered with left join)

Comment: In **this** way (insert override of union) you have ever the same number of bucket files.